# spring @Value doesn't load value from application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I tried to use spring @Value to get property from application.properties file. However, if I do

```
@Service
public class FooClass {

    @Value("${abc}")
    private String var;

    public String foo() {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationReader {
    @Bean
    public FooClass fooClass()
    {
        return new FooClass();
    }
}
```

I got "${abc}" assgined to var instead of the value in the property file. Any idea? guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the class a Spring-managed bean? It's difficult to see, since you didn't show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suppress the autowiring by the call

```
@Bean
public FooClass fooClass()
{
    return new FooClass();
}
```

Here you in fact manually create a new instance rather than using spring created bean.
Just remove the

```
@Bean
public FooClass fooClass()...
```

Check that `FooClass's` package is added to package scan to let spring create bean from your `@Service` annotation of `FooClass`